# How to flipped 3D data with 50% chance along x axis?

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, computer-vision

I read one paper and they mentioned as

> flipped data with 50% chance along x-axis.

Given an input data is 40x40x24. How can I perform the above requirement? I am trying the bellow code using python 2.7 but I am not sure about "50% chance" meaning

```
data_flip = np.flipud(data)
data_flip = data[:, ::-1, :]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in order to choose out of `n` elements with probability `p` you can simply use: `np.random.rand(n) < p`. [`r = np.random.rand()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) generates a number from a uniform distribution over `[0, 1)`, so the probability that `r` is smaller than some constant `p` (where `p` is in [0,1]) is exactly `p`. This probability is actually the [CDF of the distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Cumulative_distribution_function), which in this case where a=0 and b=1 is:

```
F(p) = 0, p<0
       p, 0<=p<=1
       1, p>1
```

Second, to flip the data along the x axis use `np.fliplr` rather than `np.flipud` (which flips along the y axis):

```
# generate a 3D array size 3x3x5
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
A = np.tile( np.expand_dims(A, axis=2), (1,1,5) )
# index the 3rd axis with probability 0.5
p = 0.5
idxs = np.random.rand(A.shape[2]) < p
# flip left-right the chosen arrays in the 3rd dimension
A[:,:,idxs] = np.fliplr(A[:,:,idxs])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you check the last line `AA[:,:,idxs] = np.fliplr(AA[:,:,idxs]) `. Is it A, instead of AA? In addition, could you explain what is meaning of `50% chance`?

Comment: `AA` should be `A` - thanks, fixed that. I also elaborated on the 50% chance. the first 3 lines in the attached code are just aimed to generate some data to work with (which you already have).

Comment: Ah I see, Sorry about that. The idea of this is randomly chose one slice with prob is 0.5 and flip it. Thanks so much